# Gradle Can't Resolve Java 9 `failedFuture` Even Though Using Java 11

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I've been stuck on this for a couple of days now, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have a situation where I have a service using Java 11, however when I try to run a `gradlew buld` I get a compilation error:

```java
error: cannot find symbol
        new ResponseFutureImpl<>(failedFuture(exception));
                                 ^
```

This is happening in a test file. However, when I run the test by itself it runs fine, and IntelliJ doesn't complain about not being able to find `failedFuture`.

Things I've tried:

- Checking java compiler settings, gradle settings, and project / module settings in IntelliJ to confirm they are set to JDK 11.
- Set     `sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11 targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11` in my `build.gradle` file.
- Checked gradle build scan to confirm it's using JDK 11
- Confirmed JAVA_HOME is pointing to correct JDK
- Invalidated IntelliJ caches
- Ran `gradle build` with `--refresh-dependencies` and `--rerun-tasks`
- Deleted `~/.gradle` and reran `gradlew build`
- Had someone with a fresh install of IntelliJ clone the project and try running on their machine, but they hit the same issue.

I'm plum out of ideas, and this seems like a very strange issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try changing this property in gralde-wrapper.properties

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0-bin.zip

Comment: Where the `failedFuture` is declared? Is it a library method? Or method in your project?